# Allow me to flag a comment as obsolete after previously upvoting it

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags

There was a comment thread started up to resolve a content dispute on an answer. I upvoted one of the comments in that thread, as did several others, to show support.

Once the dispute was over, people started cleaning up their comments; however the comment I'd upvoted was written by someone who wasn't around any more. With all the other comments deleted, they probably wouldn't even see any notifications from this thread, and would likely never return to it.

Instead of `@pinging` them and asking for a removal, because that seems like I'm trying to control them, I wanted to simply flag the comment as obsolete which is a janitorial action with no implication of hostility or disagreement.

Alas, the entire flag dialog is unreachable on comments you've upvoted.

Can it be reachable please? Even if in a limited form?

Comment: inb4 why add to mod workload just ask the comment author

Comment: Actually, now that you put it that way, if the entire point of comments is that they're ephemeral by nature and can go away at any time, why prevent flagging them *at all*? Whether or not you upvote a comment isn't going to keep it from being deleted.

Comment: This seems to have been implemented already.

Comment: @Laurel: Agreed. Yay!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@Laurel has pointed out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255656/allow-me-to-flag-a-comment-as-obsolete-after-previously-upvoting-it?noredirect=1#comment354137_255656), this now appears to work.

Thus, though I can't do so myself, I propose that this is now [status-fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-fixed).